# replace all formula with values using command line + libreofface

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc, openxlsx

Now I have to use (c++ excel library) to read the sheet values. But it doesn't support for converting calc formula to readable value, so how can I convert calc .ods file to .xlsx file with replace all formula with result value using command line? . Thanks.
Now. I had tried this

```
libreoffice --convert-to xml dayta.ods
libreoffice --convert-to xlsx dayta.xml
```

but it doesn't work. The xlsx file still filled with formula.

Comment: Welcome! First of all, you should assume that there are cells in the Calc source file that contain images of formulas, and not calculated values. Are you sure the source file is correct?

Comment: The next step is to make sure that all functions used in formulas are compatible with Excel (for example, user-defined functions - macros, or exotic functions like CURRENT() or STYLE()). If you open the original spreadsheet and do File-Save As-Excel File, will that workbook open correctly in Excel?